# Creating a landing page using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I`m working on a landing page.

left side - contact us form
right side - logo, under it 3 red circles (inline) with font-awesome icons that will function as buttons for information.

I`m using bootstrap  for that, so I have my background and the logo on the right top. (managed to make it responsive and fit all devices).

I`m having problem with the 3 red circles and making them responsive with, the red circles are too small on the mobile.

and another issue is that I want to make some space between them, no matter when I do I cant make it happen. The max-width of the 3 red circles should be the max-width of the logo above them.

So this is what I did for the circle:

```css
.circle {
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ff043b;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="icons" class="fullwidth">
  <div id="circle1" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circle2" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circle3" class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The max-width of the 3 red circles should be the max-width of the logo above them ... yet there's no jsFiddle with the images above them.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, why don't you nest your circles in divs with a class of col-xs-4 and let them display block on mobile?

Comment: why don't you add a min-width?